# How can I fix the 'agent cannot start' error in OSConfigAgent on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

OSConfigAgent[1594]: 2023-06-04T08:35:51.0664Z OSConfigAgent Critical main.go:112: Error parsing metadata, agent cannot start: network error when requesting metadata, make sure your instance has an active network and can reach the metadata server: Get http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/?recursive=true&alt=json&wait_for_change=true&last_etag=0&timeout_sec=60: dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connect: network is unreachable

Getting this issue in gcp cloud ? how to resolve it

last thing i did is i removed all python3 folders using rm something/python3/*
and another thing is my disk is full almost

Comment: Resize both the instance and the disk size larger - or start over with a larger instance size.